# How to use Azure CloudShell for Continuous Deployment

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-cloud-shell

I am using CloudShell to deploy Azure Services using PowerShell Scripts. It's a great experience.Now I want to use CloudShell to automate deployment. I am maintaining a solution in TFS/VSTS.

**Is there any way or workaround to call OR to get the CloudShell instance or to run Powershell on CloudShell using some Batch command or C# or else.**

> Is any CloudShell API exist to use CloudShell service from .Net

Comment: what do you mean by cloudshell? in the portal shell?

Comment: I mean to say behind the scene CloudShell (yes Portal Shell) might be calling any API. If that API is open source then I can use it. It will help me to test any deployments without the need to create VM. My operation team always wants a VM to test Deployment and CloudSell itself provides dedicated VM along with all necessary installation so If I want to use it for continues deployment then is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no API behind the CloudShell, but its just a bash shell that's using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/overview?view=azure-cli-latest) and [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-4.4.0). You can use those on your own.

Comment: Is there a way to run the PowerShell script (stored inside CloudShell storage) at a particular time or can we install a job or something?

Comment: well, that sounds like a really clumsy way of doing that, you can download the script from that storage, but you are better of not using that storage account to store data. it is 101% not convenient, just use your repo, grab latest commit and run those scripts

Comment: I am thinking to use Git rather than storage

Answer (score 0):

You can access the [open source project for Azure Cloud Shell on github](https://github.com/Azure/CloudShell) and [run the Azure Cloud Shell container locally using docker](https://github.com/Azure/CloudShell#running-the-cloud-shell-image-locally). Not sure this meets your need, but it's a cool option nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge, Azure Cloud is an interactive, browser-accessible for managing Azure resources. You cannot use Azure Cloud Shell for Continuous Deployment.

**Note:** Azure Cloud Shell is an interactive, browser-accessible shell for managing Azure resources. It gives you the flexibility of choosing the shell experience that best suits the way you work. Linux users can opt for a Bash experience, while Windows users can opt for PowerShell.

For more details, refer "[**Overview of Azure Cloud Shell (Preview)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-shell/overview)"

Comment: this makes about zero sense. you can use both az cli and powershell without cloudshell